# How to concatenate multiple LWP get commands

Tags: perl, lwp

I am using LWP to get html from three different web pages (defined dynamically) and assign it to a scalar `$content`. Sometimes one or more of the pages I search will not exist, so `get` will sometimes return undef. How should I handle this, such that `$content` will include all successful get commands?

I have the following which works if only one of my `get` requests returned a defined value:

```
unless ($content = get $page_one)
{
   unless ($content = get $page_two)
   {
      unless ($content = get $page_three)
      {
         $content = "";
      }
   }
}
```

but obviously, it doesn't get all the content if more than one page was going to return a defined value.

Comment: What does *doesn't seem to be working as I expected* mean? I see nothing wrong with your first attempt

Comment: @Borodin Right, it turned out my problem was external; I updated my question to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you nest conditions and make them depend on success of previous gets, when they shouldn't.

```
my $result;
if ($content = get $page_one) { $result .= $content }
if ($content = get $page_two) { $result .= $content }
if ($content = get $page_three) { $result .= $content }
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
$content = join '', grep { $_ } map { get($_) } ($page_one, $page_two, $page_three);
```

Look at it from right to left:

At first I construct an array with the addresses to the three pages.

That is handed over to [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) which retrieves each page returning an array of three elements. Each element is either the content for the page or `undef`.

The [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) then throws away the `undef`s.

And the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) finally concatenates the content that has been retrieved successfully.